# Angularjs regular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

In my Angularjs application I need to have regular expression for two patterns for form validation with the following condition.

Pattern 1 :

The input box should accept alphanumeric with no space and it should also allow the user to use the characters like `~!@#$-_` any where in the string, except these characters non of the other characters should be allowed like `(%, &, ^ etc)`. It should not allow leading/trailing whitespace also.

Examples :

```
 ab@4_w    :  valid
 sd!tye123  : valid
 sd%tye123  :  Invalid
 sd*tye123  :  Invalid
```

$scope.pattern1 = [\w~!@#\$-]+

Pattern 2:
Should allow only alphanumeric with no space and no other characters including (_). It should not allow leading/trailing whitespace also.

Examples :

```
  a4hgg5  : Valid
  a4_6hy   : Invalid
  a@yb    : invalid
```

$scope.pattern2 = [\w]+

`$scope.pattern1` and `$scope.pattern2`  needs to be modified to meet my above requirements.

Comment: Can you please precise the requirements? Can there be leading/trailing whitespace? Should a dot be allowed and where? Are `~!@#$-_` allowed anywhere in the string?  If possible, please provide a fiddle to test.

Comment: Please clarify the requirements. You say you need `_` in the question, but, in the comment, you say you do not want to match `_`. A JS fiddle would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should not allow leading/trailing whitespace.

In both cases, add the `ng-trim="false"` attribute to the `input` element.

> The input box should accept alphanumeric with no space and it should also allow the user to use the characters like `~!@#$-_` any where in the string, except these characters non of the other characters should be allowed like (`%`, `&`, `^` etc).

The pattern you have is correct, but escaping characters that do not have to be escaped is not recommended, use:

```
^[\w~!@#$-]+$
```

Where `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

NOTE: if you pass the pattern as a string, do not add `^` and `$` anchors, but double the backslashes: `"[\\w~!@#$-]+"`.

> Should allow only alphanumeric with no space and no other characters including (`_`).

It is much easier: `^[a-zA-Z]+$`. Same comment about anchors as above applies.

Comment: Wiktor, How can I restrict the allowed characters to be maximum 32 characters in the above regular expressions?

Comment: Use a limiting quantifier: `^[\w~!@#$-]{1,32}$` - `{1,32}` means *repeat 1 to 32 times*. To allow an empty string, use `{0,32}`. No spaces in between.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^[\w~!@#\$-]+$
```

### Explanation

1. `^` Begin of string
2. `[\w~!@#\$-]+` Any number of the Characters you want, (note the need to escape `$` like `\$`)
3. `$`End of string

See in [Action on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qTLrbX/1). If you want empty strings to be valid, specify `*` instead of `+` for the quantifier. Also, when using `\w` you do not need to set the `i` flag, since it already covers both upper and lowercase letters.

Comment: Even though in your solution [\w~!@#\$-]+ there is no underscore, but still underscore is getting allowed, how come?

Comment: Thats because `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-Z0-9_]`, funny I know, i also dont know who specified this as an "word-character", but thats how it is...

Comment: Now if I need to accept all alpha numeric with no space and no underscore (_), what I have to do?

Comment: @MadasuK: You are contradicting yourself: *But it should allow only the  `~!@#$-_` along with alphanumerics.* You stated you need to match  `_`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew true, but for the sake of answering, you take away the `\w` and add `A-Za-Z0-9` instead

Comment: ok that solves the issue. Can you please restrict leading and ending white space also for your solution [\w~!@#\$-]+

Comment: what do you mean by **resrict**, those should already be forbidden